# knockout.js complex obeservable?

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I have the following model

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.appointment = {
        title: ko.observable(),
        description: ko.observable(),
        time: ko.observable(),
        address1: ko.observable(),
        address2: ko.observable(),
        phone: ko.observable(),
        email: ko.observable(),
     }
);
```

And then mapped by json data, which will produce an observableArray of appointment items, called `appointment_set`

I have a view which binds to the appointment element of the model, but when I set the `appointment` element with an element from the observableArray, the view won't update with the values, see below:

```
viewmodel.appointment = viemodel.appointment_set()[0];
```

I think it's because `appointment`itself is not observable, how do I fix this?

Comment: I suspect the real problem is that `appointment_set()[0].xyz` is *not* observable. This would then mean that `appointment.xyz` is *not* observable. Alternatively, if that is not the case then, it may be that the `.appointment = ..` occurs *after* the VM is bound in which case only the objects (in the now "disconnected") appointment object are bound - binding happens *per observable object*. If so, changing `appointment` to an observable (i.e. `self.appointment = ko.observable({...})`) and using `.appointment(theNewAppointment)` (and binding to `.appointment().title`, etc) would fix the issue.

Comment: cool I didn't know you can create observable like this `observable({})`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ user2246674's comment, I've change it to:

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.appointment = ko.observable({
        title: ko.observable(),
        description: ko.observable(),
        time: ko.observable(),
        address1: ko.observable(),
        address2: ko.observable(),
        phone: ko.observable(),
        email: ko.observable(),
     });
);
```

And set the appointment later like:

```
viewmodel.appointment(viewmodel.appointment_set()[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ViewModel = function(){
var self = this;
self.appointment = observableArray({
    title: ko.observable(),
    description: ko.observable(),
    time: ko.observable(),
    address1: ko.observable(),
    address2: ko.observable(),
    phone: ko.observable(),
    email: ko.observable(),
 });
};
```

use it as observableArray if you want to use the following line :

```
 viewmodel.appointment(viemodel.appointment_set()[0]);
```

Because you can't say '[0]' for an observable ... it is used only if you are dealing with observableArray .

also make sure that appointment is declared an observableArray too.

```
self.appointment=ko.observableArray();
```

Hope this might help you ... i just said from what i know ... so excuse if me if i am wrong.